# Getting the client path of a file on the server after uploading

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

[image]

I want to know the REALPATH of selected file. Like I uploaded the image. I want to know **F:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico**.

This is my code:

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
?>
</pre>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fupload" id="fupload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

Output:

Array
(
    [fupload] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ubuntu.ico
            [type] => image/x-icon
            [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php89.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1150
        )

)
```

Comment: I do not think it is possible (due to privacy/security reasons) to get the real path of the client computer.

Comment: You can create an additional textfield below and ask the user to enter the realpath of the file into it.

Comment: What is your usecase for knowing where the user keeps their copy of the file they are uploading?

Comment: You need to remember that in google chrome you can get the relative path if someone drags and uploads a folder in its entirety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't know the full path on the client system. Most browsers simply do not expose that information to webpages. Giving that information can expose information about the client system (e.g. usernames, installed software packages) and the usecases for the server knowing the path are very rare.

Comment: No. Browsers block that information in the DOM (for exactly the same reasons as they don't send it to the server when you submit the form).

Answer (score 0):

is it relevant to have the file? because if you omit enctype (uses the default) and do print_r($_POST), you got the full name as type=file is managed as type=input

Comment: at least, it was this way years ago

Comment: sorry, as many says here, depends on browsers, I think, I don't remember, I used on IE3 to choose files on shares on a intranet, so there was no need to upload the file, just to point to it. @Quentin, fyi