# PHP: Can we get the folder name from where file is uploaded?

Tags: php, file-upload

Suppose there is a folder "my_pdfs" and that contains many files, I choose the file and submit the form. Can I get the folder name "my_pfds".

I have tried this:

```
$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']
```

But this gives temporary folder path.

I want original folder name(my_pdfs) from where file has been chosen.

Comment: if `my_pdfs` is on the users machine who is selecting the file, then no, you can't get that information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the client path of a file on the server after uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986316/getting-the-client-path-of-a-file-on-the-server-after-uploading)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get that folder name on your machine because the $_FILES superglobal variable works for getting information on a file and not a folder